Sudo account reward remainder
impl pallet_staking::Config for Runtime {
    type RewardRemainder = Treasury;
}

How can I give it to sudo account

RewardRemainder need an object that implement OnUnbalanced.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/96ab6869bafb06352b282576a6395aec8e9f2705/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L164

We can simply implement one for it. Put such code in your runtime/lib.rs:
use frame_support::traits::Imbalance;
pub type NegativeImbalanceOf =
    <Balances as frame_support::traits::Currency<AccountId>>::NegativeImbalance;
pub struct ToSudo;
impl frame_support::traits::OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalanceOf> for ToSudo {
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalanceOf) {
        let numeric_amount = amount.peek();
        if let Some(k) = Sudo::key() {
            <Balances as frame_support::traits::Currency<AccountId>>::resolve_creating(&k, amount);
        } else {
            // TODO: handle no sudo key.
        }
    }
}

This code works for my Substrate version. You might need to make some tweak for your.
